# Package footnotebackref conflict with memoir

Tags: hyperref, memoir

I'm using `footnotebackref` with `memoir`. The footnote is generated and the link from the text works (from `hyperref` presumably), but no link is created from the footnote back to the text.  This appears to be a confict with memoir (though it compiles fine and I don't see any errors in the output). If in the following MWE you substitute `book` for `memoir` then it works as expected. I've run it in both pdfLaTeX and LuaTeX and the results are the same.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{footnotebackref}
\begin{document}
This is text.\footnote{This is a footnote.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wild guess, but could it be because of your pdf viewer?  Have you tried with two different ones?

Comment: Yep, I've tried multiple viewers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `footnotebackref` package works by patching `\@makefnmark`, but `memoir` does not use this. Patching `\@thefnmark` as below seems to work at least on this example, but I can't promise that there aren't other unwanted effects:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{footnotebackref}

\makeatletter
    \renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
        \let\BHFN@thefnmark\@thefnmark
        \renewcommand\@thefnmark{\hyperref[\BackrefFootnoteTag]{\BHFN@thefnmark}}%
        \BHFN@OldMakefntext{#1}}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
This is text.\footnote{This is a footnote.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yep, that does it. Both my MWE and my real world version. The only thing I noticed in the output, which might be related, is the line:

`Package fmtcount Warning: \ordinal already defined use \FCordinal instead. on input line 344.`

I don't know what that means but it compiled fine and I don't see any problems in my main text. I've marked it answered for now but if anyone sees a potential problem and has a fix that's be great.

Comment: The warning you are getting is due to both `memoir` and the `fmtcount` package trying to define `\ordinal` for similar purposes. However, from what I can tell, these are not interface compatible as one works on a counter name and the other on a literal number, hence it depends if you are using the `fmtcount` version anywhere. The `footnotebackref` code does not load `fmtcount` so this is caused by something unrelated to this question and you would be advised to create a further question with an appropriate MWE if you want help investigating.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information. Turns out that the warning did not occur from my MWE but my real world example.  I've got lots of stuff going on with that one so whenever I get around to isolating that problem I'll bring it up here.  But for now it looks like the `footnotebackref` problem is solved.  Thanks for figuring it out.

Answer (score 0):

`memoir` has many interfaces, thus seems that `footnotebackref` is not needed.

I use this patch **without** loading `footnotebackref`:

```
\newcounter{BackrefHyperFootnoteCounter}
\makeatletter
\LetLtxMacro{\mfnbr@old@footnote}{\footnote} % `letltxmacro' already required by `hyperref'
\let\mfnbr@old@makefnmark=\@makefnmark
\let\mfnbr@old@makefootmark=\makefootmark
\def\footnote{% must not insert any visible things: space, label etc.
    \stepcounter{BackrefHyperFootnoteCounter}% must not be `\refstepcounter', which include a `\ref'.
    \edef\BackrefFootnoteTag{mfnbr:\theBackrefHyperFootnoteCounter}%
    \mfnbr@old@footnote
}
\def\@makefnmark{%
    \mfnbr@old@makefnmark%
    \label{\BackrefFootnoteTag}% must not be in `\footnote', as this is "visible" to TeX.
}
\def\makefootmark{\hyperref[\BackrefFootnoteTag]{\mfnbr@old@makefootmark}}
\makeatother
```

The patch from @cyberSingularity will destroy `\multfootsep`, as it inserts the `\label` directly into `\footnote`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[colorlinks, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\newcounter{BackrefHyperFootnoteCounter}
\makeatletter
\LetLtxMacro{\mfnbr@old@footnote}{\footnote} % `letltxmacro' already required by `hyperref'
\let\mfnbr@old@makefnmark=\@makefnmark
\let\mfnbr@old@makefootmark=\makefootmark
\def\footnote{% must not insert any visible things: space, label etc.
    \stepcounter{BackrefHyperFootnoteCounter}% must not be `\refstepcounter', which include a `\ref'.
    \edef\BackrefFootnoteTag{mfnbr:\theBackrefHyperFootnoteCounter}%
    \mfnbr@old@footnote
}
\def\@makefnmark{%
    \mfnbr@old@makefnmark%
    \label{\BackrefFootnoteTag}% must not be in `\footnote', as this is "visible" to TeX.
}
\def\makefootmark{\hyperref[\BackrefFootnoteTag]{\mfnbr@old@makefootmark}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum[3]\footnote{fn1}\footnote{fn2}\lipsum
\end{document}
```